# Issue with Player Movement Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am VERY new to unity and I wrote this very basic program to move the player. This program works when there is no conditional statement on if the w key is pressed, but if you add it, the capsule is unable to move.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
{
    Vector3 cameraForward = Camera.main.transform.forward;
    cameraForward.y = 0;
    cameraForward = cameraForward.normalized;
    Vector3 moveDirection = cameraForward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position += moveDirection;
}
```

The only issue I can see with this is that the capsule is clipping into the plain, although I have a collider and a rigidbody on it. If you run this the capsule just does not move, at all. If it at all matters, I also have another line of code that sets the rotation of the capsule to 0, 0, 0, 0 every frame.

Comment: Why is it that Unity coders never show the entire method or at least what calls it?  For all we know you are calling this from Start().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Input.GetKeyDown()` only triggers once per key-press. Your biggest issue (there may be others) is that that will only move the player forward for a single tick. You want `Input.GetKey()` ([Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html)) instead.